# WPF Inline Editing in textblock based on linenumbers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inline, textblock

I want to highlight some lines in a textblock. These lines are decided dynamically. How do I do it? 
For eg- I want to highlight all the lines containing files tag, how do I do it?

[image: Content of textblock]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work for you:

```
foreach(System.Windows.Documents.Run run in textBlock.Inlines.OfType<System.Windows.Documents.Run>())
{
    if (run.Text.Contains("<files ") || run.Text.Contains("</files>"))
    {
        run.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
    }
}
```

You can could also use regular expressions to do the matching instead of text compares if you need more flexibility.

Comment: I added text in the textblock by appending text. Therefore the run is covering the whole text in the textblock, thus this loop is running only once.
However I want the highlighting to take place depending on line.

Comment: Your example had each XML tag on each own line.  Are you stating now that all the text will now be on one line and you want highlight only those potions of the single line that are the <files> tag?

Comment: I was doing some mistake. Now I figured out. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Textblock inline to do highlights, for example

```
 TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                    tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                    tb.Margin = new Thickness(10);
                    tb.Inlines.Add("<xml...> ");
                    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("<Configuration ") 
                                       { 
                                         FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                                         Foreground = Brushes.Blue });

                    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run( new LineBreak())....
```

Comment: How can I highlight specific line numbers dynamically then ?